# Functional reactive programming — is Fay expressive enough?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, reactive-programming, fay

So I'm doing a fairly involved javascript/html client with lots of ajax calls and other involvements of callback-ism. I'm entertaining the thought of using Fay for this purpose. I'm aware of Elm. Tried it and liked the FRP elements. Now I'm looking to know if similar structure is possible in Fay.

Are there any concrete examples of FRP in Fay out there at this point?

Edit: Migrated to Programmers.Stackexchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186102/functional-reactive-programming-is-fay-expressive-enough

Comment: Is Javascript not FRP enough for you? :-)

Comment: Oh. You made me go look for a javascript frp library (again). [I found this](https://github.com/raimohanska/bacon.js). Seems it has to involve a lot of boilerplate that takes away a lot of the elegance though.

Comment: @worldsayshi: I think any JavaScript code is going to involve a lot of boilerplate which will take some elegance away. [Arrowlets](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/arrowlets/) and [FlapJax](http://www.flapjax-lang.org/) may also interest you.

Comment: I was shown a demonstration combining bacon.js (frp lib) and fay: [code](https://github.com/NicolasT/Bacon-n-Fay), [demo](http://nicolast.github.com/Bacon-n-Fay/BaconFliesLikeAnArrow.html), [source](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/17gavl/what_you_consider_advanced_haskell_topics/c85ncwl).